# How do I add an ajax item on the submit button?

Tags: ajax, webforms

I created a form using the module "Webform". Now I want to add an #ajax item to the submit button.

Here's what I already did:

```
use \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
{
  $form['#submit']['#ajax'] = array(
    'callback' => '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\DefaultController::process_form_submission'
  );
}
```

The '#submit' field of the form now looks like this:

```
'#submit' => array(2)
    '0' => string(12) "::submitForm"
    '#ajax' => array(1)
        'callback' => string(72) "\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\DefaultController::process_form_submission"
```

But the `process_form_submission` function is not called. Instead the page reloads on submit as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = array(
        'callback' => '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\DefaultController::process_form_submission',
'event' => 'click',
      );
```