# How do I make a submit through AJAX?

Tags: 8, ajax, webforms

I created a webform in Drupal 8. While submitting the form, it reloads the whole page, even I had selected inline submission in confirmation message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I submit a form via AJAX?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232909/how-do-i-submit-a-form-via-ajax)

Comment: yeah its duplicate . i am not able to get clear idea in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232909/how-do-i-submit-a-form-via-ajax

Comment: the answer there is no longer valid, ajax is in the latest webform release, see issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2757491

Answer (score 0):

Just checked your issue by upgrading [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) to version [8.x-5.0-beta15](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/releases/8.x-5.0-beta15). After enabling AJAX on the form and setting the confirmation to either `inline` or `message` the confirmation worked as expected. I did needed to clear my cache though.

So try upgrading the Webform module and clear your cache.