# Drupal 8: Prevent webform from saving IP

Tags: 8, webforms

About the webform module: It always stores the IP with a submission unless it's set as confidential. Is there a way to not store the IP while leaving it as not confidential?

In `webform/src/WebformSubmissionForm.php` is the function `save` where it sets the `remote_addr`. Is there any way to hook this? I don't think it works with a custom webform handler...

Thanks! Looking forward for your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could override the save function of webform/src/WebformSubmissionForm.php, but as you specifically ask for a hook and because this is probably also the easiest solution you can remove the field value set by the form before the entity gets saved:

```
use Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave() for webform submissions.
 */
function mymodule_webform_submission_presave(WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {
  $webform_submission->remote_addr->value = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this code..

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/*
* Implement hook_form_alter()
*/
function my_module_form_alter(&$form,$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#validate'][] = 'custom_form_validate';                 
}


function custom_form_validate($form, $form_state) {         
  $ip = \Drupal::request()->getClientIp();
  $form_state->setValue('remote_addr', $ip);
}
```

Comment: I tried it with `$form_state->setValue('remote_addr', '');` since I don't want the IP to be stored but this doesn't work. The IP gets stored anyway. However I have to mention that my custom validate function is called via AJAX (see this [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232909/how-do-i-submit-a-form-via-ajax)). I don't know if it doesn't work because of this and I haven't tested it any other way.